# Pymongo cursor not found

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Does anyone know how to trigger the cursor not found error in PyMongo artificially? Thanks

Based on what I found this error is triggered after the cursor is inactive for more than 10 minutes. So I did this

```
cursor = coll.find()
time.sleep(9000)
for row in cursor:
  time.sleep(1000)
  print(row['scores'])
```

but python successfully run this without giving me the error.

Answer (score 0):

To kill cursor you can use [killCursors](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/killCursors/#mongodb-dbcommand-dbcmd.killCursors) command. You can also change the limit via `cursorTimeoutMillis` option, see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/parameters/#mongodb-parameter-param.cursorTimeoutMillis).

As for:

> but python successfully run this without giving me the error.

You should remember that cursor works in a batch mode. So you don't call server until the previously received batch items are not iterated on the client side. I vote that if you iterate the items in the received batch (usually `batchSize` is 20 by default), then next server call (with `$getMore` command) will fail

Comment: I  did both killing the cursor and change the cursor timeout, but it didn't trigger the error

Comment: Do you mean during iterating the loop, the request is only made every 20 iterations(by default)?

Comment: `only made every 20 iterations` - yes